# Link static library that itself has dependencies

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, static-libraries, xmppframework

I have created a static library for iOS that uses the [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS). I followed all steps in the getting started guide, and I'm pretty sure that I did it right because I have created iOS apps that used the framework directly before and it went without problems.

However, now I wanted to outsource the XMPP stuff into a static library which I then linked into my "client" iOS app. The linking itself is working well, and a call to a simple method inside the library that just does a `NSLog` also works fine. But as soon as I start to use a method inside the library which uses any of the XMPPFramework specific stuff (such as connecting a stream), I get a shitload of linking errors.

Are the dependencies of my static library somehow lost when I link it into the app project? Do I have to add them all over again there? The funny thing is, when I add e.g. Security.framework and CFNetwork.framework to my app, just like I have done in the static library, some of the errors disappear. And also I had to include the header search path `/usr/include/libxml2` in both the library and the app.

But even when I add every dependency listed in under the link provided above (except for the source code files), there are still 55 linker errors left (as opposed to 81 without adding them).
[image: An excerpt of the linker errors]

Comment: It might be a silly suggestion, but did you remember to add the libxml library to the link phase of your target in Xcode?

Comment: Indeed I hadn't, but when I did it solved the problem! But why do I need to do this, it was never necessary to build apps that were directly using XMPPFramework?

Comment: I'm curious about this as I'm in a similar situation. Please do let us know if you get to the bottom of this.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. So I have created a statis library and XMPPFramework is part of this static library. My structure is as follows :
 •  I have workspace say - MyWorkspace
 •  I have application project in workspace say - MyMainProject
 •  I have created a static library say - MyChatClient
 •  Now I have closed everything. Created pod file with workspace as MyWorkspace, xcodeproject as MyChatClient.
 • Chat client is to be used in  MyMainProject so that it creates an abstraction.

Getting similar kind of issues as mentioned in above question.

Comment: @drew - Which target to add it to? app or static library.